# Manage positions of divs

Tags: html, css

I have some divs (1, 2 and 3 are wrapped in container):

[image]

And I need to do change these divs according responsive design like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that? Maybe using grids?

Comment: @Cody Gray care to explain why opened this question that doesn't show any effort at all?

Comment: @dippas Because "effort" is never required in a Stack Overflow question. Lack of effort is not, and has never been, a close reason.

Comment: I've seen dozens if not more of this type of question being closed.

Comment: I've seen dozens of blatantly off-topic questions *not* get closed, @dippas. Not everything on Stack Overflow is perfect. If you'd like to flag other questions that you think are incorrectly closed, please go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CSS-Grid** helps us to achieve this without using any other extra wrappers and without hiding un-hiding stuff using media queries. I am using `grid-areas` concept of `CSS-Grid` in this case. Though the same can be achieved using `grid-lines` concept of `CSS-Grid` as well.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1rem;

  /* Placing grid-items inside our grid */
  grid-template-areas:
    "one one one one four four four"
    "one one one one four four four"
    "two two two two four four four"
    "two two two two four four four"
    "three three three three four four four";
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5.5;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    width: 70%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "one one one"
      "one one one"
      "two two two"
      "two two two"
      "four four four"
      "four four four"
      "four four four"
      "four four four"
      "three three three";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Todo | Asynchronous Dynamaic Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <main class="main">
          <div class="one"> 1</div>
          <div class="two"> 2</div>
          <div class="three">3</div>
          <div class="four">4</div>
    <main>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** The same can be achieved using **flexbox** as well however, we will need additional code. Some content simply needs to be hidden in small screens and other shown along with the `order` property of `flexbox.`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using flexbox, but don't think about grid-row!
Thanks

Comment: That's also possible with flexbox:

Comment: Shall I do this for you :)

Comment: Using flexbox with order?

Comment: Yup: With that only :)

Comment: And using flex-direction:column :)